# Existence of time in some other universe

Tags: time, multiverse

Is it necessary that time should exist in another universe if it (universe) is there? How do we perceive timelessness?

Comment: This seems to be about fictional physics right now. Maybe you could specify what sort of universe you talk about? A Multiverse theory universe? M-theory? Also, this question reminds me of [this diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/File:Spacetime_dimensionality.svg), which may be useful to you. (See http://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Spacetime#Privileged_character_of_3.2B1_spacetime)

Comment: @Manishearth- That diagram is very helpful. But I have few doubts. Can I start a new post regarding this?

Comment: Well, the current question is apt to be closed as off topic (See our policy on [fictional physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)). If your new question is just a more specific version of this, I suggest you modify this one via an edit.

Comment: @Inquisitive: Yes please. Thats the use of Physics.SE. But, please use our search bar to find, whether any related questions exist already... Please be specific on your question. A good question on these tags would definitely get a lot of upvotes :-)

Comment: Hi @Inquisitive: I'm closing this question(v2) since e.g. everyone can claim that according to their definition of _another universe,_ there is no time.

Comment: Hi @Anixx: A philosophy tag is not allowed, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/80/2451) meta Phys.SE post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Time is just a construct of man. It is simply the length of observation. Even with a static situation, it can still be observed.

Time exists anywhere there is observation, just like the empty set.

Something which is timeless is said to be unaffected by time, unchanging. Thus, timelessness would just be the embodiment of that.

A good example of timelessness is a single length of time, as it is unaffected by time, and will be - for all time, any time, or no time.

Comment: Why don't time change with time?

Comment: @Inquisitive - Time can change, but it will not be affected by an external time. No matter how much time elapses, the time it takes light to travel one light year will still be one year. If I am timing the light, timing how long it takes me to cook dinner will not affect how long the light takes. It may tell me that I need to start multi-tasking while I make stir fry though :)

Comment: "No matter how much time elapses, the time it takes light to travel one light year will still be one year" But sometimes time dependent on velocity, isn't it?

Comment: @Inquisitive - velocity is a rate of change. For change to occur there must be an observation made over a length of time. Velocity is dependent on time, because without time, all you would have was position. Just think of a picture of an airplane flying. Sure, the plane has velocity, but you cannot tell anything about that velocity from the picture.